# How to get a notification if any new event happened

Tags: android

**I wrote a code to get a news RSS feed for a specific university and I want to add a new feature for my application which is getting a notification if a new item added to the xml file ... if there is a new news , I mean some thing like this :
[image]

can any one help me by giving me a sample code or project for something like this or any link for an article or tutorial ?**

Comment: This is part of Paranoid Android's HALO feature, which adds a persistent floating bubble on top of the system UI to provide easy access to notifications. This was inspired by Facebook Chatheads. The source code is available in [`BaseStatusBar.java`](https://github.com/ParanoidAndroid/android_frameworks_base/blob/jb43/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/BaseStatusBar.java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's not a notification. That's a widget. I think this would be very helpfull. [Widget tut](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/)

Comment: That is NOT a widget, that is ParanoidAndroid's HALO system. This is NOT the answer the OP wanted.

Comment: -1, This is not a widget. It's a view that is added to its own separate window via the `WindowManager` (see line 587 of [`BaseStatusBar.java`](https://github.com/ParanoidAndroid/android_frameworks_base/blob/jb43/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/BaseStatusBar.java)).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a real notification? The widget update is only visible when you look at the Home screen, while the notification is always visible.

Just a thought.

Comment: can you clarify your answer more please ^^! cuz I 'm a beginner.

Comment: -1, This is not a widget. It's a view that is added to its own separate window via the WindowManager (see line 587 of BaseStatusBar.java).